# How to get deviceid of message in Azure function that is triggered by IOThub message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have an Azure function that is triggered by IOThub. So in the Azure function, I have

```
public static async Task Run(EventData myIoTHubMessage1, TraceWriter log)
```

How do I get the device id from the Event Data.

I tried

```
log.Info("devid="+myIoTHubMessage1.SystemProperties["ConnectionDeviceId"]);
```

It gave an error saying

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

the following document says that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct

ConnectionDeviceId contains the deviceId. Would anybody know how to retrieve the deviceid from EventData or should I use some other class.

Answer (score 4):

You can get device ID from `SystemProperties`:

```cs
public static async Task Run(EventData myIoTHubMessage1, TraceWriter log)
{
    var deviceId = myIoTHubMessage1.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"];
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (EventData receivedEvent : receivedEvents) {
       String deviceId = (String) receivedEvent.getProperties().get("deviceId");
       log.info("From:" + deviceId);
    }
```