# IOT Hub Events into Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have created a very simple Azure Function that wires into the IoT Hub to capture the built-in events endpoint (with a custom consumer group, but that's not the issue).

The issue I'm having is the message that's sent to the endpoint.   It doesn't identify *which* device or *which* module, or even what the event is.     Is it a device-twin update, a message from a module, a module-twin update - and where - from device code, module code?    Am I missing something here?    How can I determine which device/module, etc sent the event?

The screenshots show the canned messaging -- basically taking the event message and dumping it to logs (the default constructor for a function).

The canned code that came with it:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log) {

    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");

}
```

[image: function integrate]

[image: function log]

Comment: Will [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954429/1171619) help?

Comment: @Mikhail -- I'll give it a whirl.  I guess I didn't realize there was more to the message that's coming in other than just a raw string.   Let me play with what you suggested - and maybe create an answer for it, so if it works for me, I can mark it answered.

Comment: That doesn't work -- it's depending on a Service Bus back-end, and that's not what I have - it's just a plain old *string* -- done by the shell basic of creating it in the template.   

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log) {

    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");

Comment: I updated the question to show more details.  Didn't realize I pasted the same image twice.

Comment: It's not service bus, it's Event Hubs. See my answer.

Comment: Regarding this piece of your question: "Is it a device-twin update, a message from a module, a module-twin update": If you listen to the "events" endpoint, which appears is what you are trying here, you will only get device-to-cloud messages. No twin updates etc.

Comment: If there aren't any custom endpoints defined, all of them end up going into "events" - even device twin changes (at least, that's been my experience so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your function to accept `EventData` as input parameter instead of string. That will give you access to event metadata, e.g. device ID from `SystemProperties`:

```cs
public static async Task Run(EventData myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    var deviceId = myIoTHubMessage.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"];
    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message from  {deviceId}");
}
```

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct) for a list of system properties.

Comment: Is there a reference I need to add to this?   It's not liking EventData,     This was created by the default "IoT Hub" function option.

Comment: It needs this 

#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using System;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

I'll play and mark you answered once I see data I like.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail -- this works - but still doesn't tell me **what** is happening.  I can determine only it was from a Device or a Module -- and then a "chunk of JSON".    Is there no easier method to capture device-twin changes more clearly?      Or a full message body?

Answer (score 2):

another option (no additional assemblies):

```
using System;

public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, IDictionary<string, object> properties, TraceWriter log)
{
   log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
   foreach (var prop in properties)
      log.Info($"\t{prop.Key} = {prop.Value}");
}
```